# gulp-watch - как при изменении/добавлении папки/файла запускать browser-sync?

Tags: gulp, browsersync, gulp-watch

Приветствую.

Стоит задача - запускать browserSync, если я добавляю в проект или удаляю из него указанную папку (/js/), или добавляю/удаляю/изменяю js-файлы в ней (все это делается вручную).

gulpfile.js выглядит следующим образом:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
        watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', ['webserver', 'watch']);

var path = {
    watch: {
        js: '../js/**/*.js',
    },
};

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'localhost'
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Здесь browserSync срабатывает только в случае, если я изменил js-файл, и если при этом папка /js/ с файлом существовала до запуска gulp.

Подскажите решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: Наверно здесь ошибка `js: '../js/**/*.js',` укажите правильный путь к жс файлам, они ни как не могут быть на уровень выше галпфайла. Хотя я  вы не показали вашу структуру проекта.

Comment: Папка /js/ находится на уровень выше, а в ней могут быть другие папки с js-файлами, все правильно. Если бы было неправильно, то browserSync не запускался бы, когда я редактирую файл.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как у вас устроен проект. Попробуйте запускать задачу `webserver` перед задачей `watch` т.е. чтобы было так `gulp.task('watch', ['webserver'], function() {`, а задача `default` стала такой `gulp.task('default', ['watch']);`.

Comment: Попробовал, это ничего не меняет.